# Fullscreen swf blocking facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a problem with signing in to facebook when my swf is in fullscreen mode.
The popup is blocked somehow and user can't enter his/her credentiatials.

I am using fullScreenInteractive mode. In fullScreen mode the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go out of fullscreen mode by yourself anytime you need an html popup to be visible (think of flash fullscreen mode as an additional window over your browser window, anything happening in the page will be invisible):

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
```

this is not only for authentication, but also for sharing, requesting, inviting, any popup...
You can't go back to fullscreen automatically after authentication either, since it requires a mouse click.

A kind of workaround would be to store an "unvoluntary out of fullscreen" flag and use the next mouse click event to go back to fullscreen, but IMO cleanest way would be by a flash back-to-fullscreen yes/no popup